# Ramda Groupby with array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, ramda.js

I have the data something like below

```
[
   ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 
   ['A', 'F', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
   ['A', 'B', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1'],
   ['A', 'F', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1'],
]
```

If i do group by from ramda with 1st index it will give some thing like below

```
cosnt groupdByRows = R.groupBy((row) => row[1], rows)

{
  B: [[A,B,C,D,E]]
  F: [[A,F,C,D,E]]
}
```

I want the result to include the duplicate rows aswell like below

```
{
  B: [[A,B,C,D,E], [A,B,C1,D1,E1]]
  F: [[A,F,C,D,E],[A,F,C1,D1,E1] ]
}
```

How can i achieve this using Ramda ?

Comment: Have you actually [tried this](https://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20rows%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%5B%27A%27%2C%20%27B%27%2C%20%27C%27%2C%20%27D%27%2C%20%27E%27%5D%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%5B%27A%27%2C%20%27F%27%2C%20%27C%27%2C%20%27D%27%2C%20%27E%27%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%5B%27A%27%2C%20%27B%27%2C%20%27C1%27%2C%20%27D1%27%2C%20%27E1%27%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%5B%27A%27%2C%20%27F%27%2C%20%27C1%27%2C%20%27D1%27%2C%20%27E1%27%5D%2C%0A%5D%0A%0AgroupBy%20%28row%20%3D>%20row%5B1%5D%2C%20rows%29)?  It looks like it works to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to achieve it. For each `row` it uses `row[1]` as the key, and adds the`row` into array stored at this key in the accumulator object `acc` If there is nothing stored, it creates and empty array.

```js
const { reduce } = R;
const arr = [  ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
  ['A', 'F', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
  ['A', 'B', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1'],
  ['A', 'F', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1'],
];

const groupdByRows = reduce((acc, row) => {
  const key = row[1];
  return {
    ...acc,
    [key]: [...(acc[key] || []), row]
  };
}, {}, arr);

console.log(groupdByRows);
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't like rambda, since its types are flawed and package sizes are bad.

so here is fnxt implementation

`npm i fnxt` and:

```
import {groupBy, map} from 'fnxt/array';
import {pipe} from 'fnxt/pipe';

let x = [
  ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
  ['A', 'F', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
  ['A', 'B', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1'],
  ['A', 'F', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1'],
];    

let result = pipe(
  groupBy((e:string[]) => e[1]),
  map((e)=> [e[0][1],e]),
  Object.fromEntries
)(x);

console.log(result)

//{
//  B: [ [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' ], [ 'A', 'B', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1' ] ],
//  F: [ [ 'A', 'F', 'C', 'D', 'E' ], [ 'A', 'F', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1' ] ]
//}
```